# drive can be only called from MainThread

Tags: ios, rx-swift

after presenting new UIViewController by code, every where(in viewModel or viewController) using .Drive, I get this error:
`drive* family of methods can be only called from MainThread`

this is how I present new ViewController:

```
func goToVerifyPage() {

    let verifyVC = VerifyViewController()
    verifyVC.modalTransitionStyle = .flipHorizontal
    self.present(verifyVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

and inside VerifyViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        confirmVerifyCodeBTN.rx.tap
            .asDriver()
            .debounce(1)
            .filter({
                self.viewModel.signupEnabled
            })
            .drive(onNext:{  [weak self] _ in
                guard let verifyCode = self?.verificationCodeTF.text  else { return }
                self?.verifyActivateCode(verifyCode)
            }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

the error showed after execute .filter line.

in the previos viewController(named loginViewController) I use the same codes but did not getting any error, the only thing that's different between verifyViewController and loginViewController is, using storyboard to presenting that ViewController(loginViewController).

**update:** 
when I using this codes for presenting verifyViewController every things going fine:

```
func goToVerifyPage() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let verifyVC = VerifyViewController()
            verifyVC.modalTransitionStyle = .flipHorizontal
            self.present(verifyVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: why this is happening? and how to make codes running?

Comment: It is happening because you are not running the code on the main thread as the library requires.  And you have to dispatch it to the correct thread.

Comment: before confirmVerifyCodeBTN.rx.tap line, I put Thread.isMainThread and it returning true. and every time I'm want presenting new ViewController using dispatch, I don't think this is a correct way.

Comment: Adding DispatchQueue.main.async is a fine solution.  The way that is more in line with rx-swift is to use:  `.observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)`

Comment: in this link https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift inside RxExample/GitHubSignup/UsingDriver > 2, i'm using this way, but they didn't get this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you were calling `goToVerifyPage()` from the result of a network request from URLSession. URLSession emits its values on a background thread so when you are ready to switch to the main thread, you should have an `.observeOn(MainThread.instance)`.

Comment: you are right. but can you explain to me why Thread.isMainThread return true? ( I put Thread.isMainThread code before confirmVerifyCodeBTN.rx.tap line in VerifyViewController)

Comment: There's not enough code to reproduce the issue so I couldn't tell you why. My guess was from previous experience of my own. It's a trap I've fallen into myself.

Comment: With latest RxSwift you may call like this `.observe(on: MainScheduler.instance)`